# Create a foreign key to already existed table using FluentApi

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

In my project, for some reason i have two separate repositories (with different `DbContext` and `schema`). Now, i need to create a foreign key from one model class in`DbContextB` to another model class in `DbContextA`, assuming that `DbContextA` is already applied to database.

```
//This is a code snippet in DbContextB.IEntityTypeConfiguration<ModelClassB>() method. 
builder
    .HasOne(col => col.PropertyA)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ModelClassB>(col => col.PropertyAId)
    .IsRequired();
```

The problem is, `DbContextB` will automatically create a table for `ModelClassA` while this table is already existed, because i run `DbContextA` migration script first.
However, One way to achieve this is to **manually insert the foreign key into generated migration script** (`ModelClassB.PropertyAId` is enough for me and i don't care about its navigation property `ModelClassB.PropertyA`).
The question is: How can i force `DbContextB` to add a foreign key without need to add its corresponding table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF Core < 5.0, the general approach for this scenario has been to use a special context only for migrations, that contains all model classes and relationships. Your app would not use this special context.

From [Ability to exclude/skip/ignore parts of the model from migrations so that a table is not created (for overlapping bounded contexts)
#2725](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2725#issuecomment-286709239) on GitHub:

> I just found a workaround
>
> 1. Create another `DbContext` that inherit your `DbContext`, for example `MigrationDbContext`. Override the `OnModelCreating` method and ingore entities that you want it's table not being generated.
>
> ```cs
>  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
>  {
>      base.OnModelCreating(builder);
>      builder.Ignore<Category>();
>  }
> ```
>
> 2. Create another class that implement `IDbContextFactory`. For example
>
> ```cs
>     public class MigrationContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MigrationDbContext>
>     {
>         public MigrationDbContext Create()
>         {
>             var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MigrationDbContext>();
>             optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");
>
>             return new MigrationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> The migration tool will discover this `MigrationContextFactory` and use the `MigrationDbContext`.

For EF Core >= 5.0, version `5.0.0-rc1` introduces the brand new `Relational:IsTableExcludedFromMigrations` annotation, that you can set e.g. by using the new `entity.ToTable(string name, bool excludedFromMigrations)` Fluent API extension method overload.

Comment: I have done this with some minor changes: 1- Since we inherit from the former `DbContext`, we should omit `builder.Ignore<Category>();` because we need `Category` table to be generate. 2- I manually changed the default schema name for each table in `DbContextA`